# Bus error with allocated memory on a heap

Tags: c++, solaris, bus-error

I have **Bus Error** in such code:

```
char* mem_original;
int int_var = 987411;
mem_original = new char [250];
memcpy(&mem_original[250-sizeof(int)], &int_var, sizeof(int));
...
const unsigned char* mem_u_const = (unsigned char*)mem_original;
...
const unsigned char *location = mem_u_const + 250 - sizeof(int);

std::cout << "sizeof(int) = " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;//it's printed out as 4
std::cout << "byte 0 = " << int(*location) << std::endl;
std::cout << "byte 1 = " << int(*(location+1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "byte 2 = " << int(*(location+2)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "byte 3 = " << int(*(location+3)) << std::endl;
int original_var = *((const int*)location);
std::cout << "original_var = " << original_var << std::endl;
```

That works well few times, printing out:

```
sizeof(int) = 4
byte 0 = 0
byte 1 = 15
byte 2 = 17
byte 3 = 19
original_var = 987411
```

And then it fails with:

```
sizeof(int) = 4
byte 0 = 0
byte 1 = 15
byte 2 = 17
byte 3 = 19
Bus Error
```

It's built & run on Solaris OS (C++ 5.12)
Same code on Linux (gcc 4.12) & Windows (msvc-9.0) is working well.

We can see:

1. memory was allocated on the heap by new[].
2. memory is accessible (we can read it byte by byte)
3. memory contains exactly what there should be, not corrupted.

So what may be reason for Bus Error? Where should I look?

**UPD:**
If I memcpy(...) `location` in the end to `original_var`, it works. But what the problem in `*((const int*)location)` ?

Comment: In addition to my answer, the right place to look is to run the program in a debugger and see which line of code crashes the program and what the pointer that caused the bus error contains.  You can then run again and single-step through to see where it got set to that.

Comment: @Davislor, unfortunately that not happens all the time. It may work many iterations before Bus Error, and reveals just at Solaris, so it's hard to debug.

Comment: Another debugging technique is to add runtime checks.  Define an inline function like: `template <type T> inline bool is_aligned( const T* p ) { return (uintptr_t)(void*)(p) % alignof(T) == 0; }`.  (If you don’t have C++11, just skip the template and use the constant 4 instead of `alignof(T)`.)  Then, whenever you do pointer math and a conversion, you can `assert` that the pointer `is_aligned`. If not, you will crash the program immediately with a diagnostic where the bug occurred.

Comment: Whoops, wrote `type` where I meant `class` or `typename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue for developers with no experience on hardware that has alignment restrictions - such as SPARC.  x86 hardware is *very* forgiving of misaligned access, albeit with performance impacts.  Other types of hardware?  `SIGBUS`.

This line of code:

```
int original_var = *((const int*)location);
```

invokes undefined behavior.  You're taking an `unsigned char *` and interpreting what it points to as an `int`.  You can't do that safely. Period.  It's undefined behavior - for the very reason you're experiencing.

You're violating the strict aliasing rule.  See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) Put simply, you can't refer to an object of one type as another type.  A `char *` does not and can not refer to an `int`.

Oracle's Solaris Studio compilers actually provide a command-line argument that will let you get away with that on SPARC hardware - `-xmemalign=1i` (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjavc/index.html).  Although to be fair to GCC, without that option, the forcing you do in your code will still `SIGBUS` under the Studio compiler.

Or, as you've already noted, you can use `memcpy()` to copy bytes around no matter what they are - as long as you know the source object is safe to copy into the target object - yes, there are cases when that's *not* true.

Comment: @BenVoigt Are you sure?  They're immune to a `SIGBUS`?  Only one of those can properly be the address of an `int` on SPARC hardware.  My experience (admittedly a while ago...) with GCC on SPARC is that they are subject to getting a `SIGBUS`, but that might be an old GCC bug in what *should* be safe code that doesn't violate strict aliasing.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep, got it.  I was misreading it - probably colored by my years-ago experiences.  I'll fix it up.

Comment: Thank you! But let's say I want to work with existing POD structure that is already in memory (char*).

Now I cant just create pointer to this structure and cast `char*` to pointer to structure.

can I create union of pointers? Like `union { mytype* myptr_; char* charptr_; };`, then without casting, just assign memory to `charptr_`, and then use `myptr_` ?

Comment: @Arkady *can I create union of pointers? Like `union { mytype* myptr_; char* charptr_; };`* No, you can't do that. It's not the *pointer* value that you can't alias, it's the object the pointer references that has a fixed type.  An arbitrary offset into an `[unsigned] char` array cannot be treated as an `int`. You can copy the data *at that address* into an `int` via `memcpy()` (unless it contains a [trap representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation)), but you can not treat it as an `int` directly no matter what you do to the pointers that refer to the object.

Comment: @Arkady If you *really* want to do this on Solaris/SPARC, you can use Oracle's compiler (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/index.html) instead of GCC, and try using the `-xmemalign=1i` command-line option to the compiler. You might incur a *significant* performance degradation.  In my experience, it will work.  Just be aware that any GCC-compiled code that you pass a misaligned `int` value to will still fail with a `SIGBUS`.

Comment: thank you for explanation. But if I have memory heap with size ~500Mb, full of different POD structures. And I know offsets of all of them. And it is very useful to just use `mytype* ptr = (mytype*)&memory_block[offset]`, and then use pointed structure, I wonder if there is no workaround without copying all those ~500Mb, and without `-xmemalign-1i`

Answer (score 3):

I get the following warning when I compile your code:

```
main.cpp:19:26: warning: cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'const int *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]
    int original_var = *((const int*)location);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This seems to be the cause of the bus error, because [improperly aligned access can cause a bus error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212585/3425536).

Comment: Even if I know there is 4 bytes in a row?

You want to say, that such `*((const int*)location` code is not correct from language perspective, even if developer knows that `location` points to enough number of bytes?

Comment: In addition to having 4 bytes in a row, the memory access must be properly aligned for `int`. The machine instruction that performs the access requires that, as pointed out in the linked answer. C++ also requires that.

Comment: don't you know how can I get `int*` from `char*` proper way, if I know there is array of `int*`?

Comment: If there's an `int` at `mem_u_const + 250 - sizeof(int)` and you can't change its location to something that's suitably aligned for `int`, then your only choice is to read the bytes of the `int` separately, something like `int original_var = (int(location[0]) << 24) | (int(location[1]) << 16) | (int(location[2]) << 8) | int(location[3]);`.

Comment: @Arkady See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule  When you coerce a `char` address to refer to an `int`, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Arkady: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903577/103167 for an explanation (mine) of why having 4 bytes in a row isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don’t have access to a SPARC right now to test this, I’m pretty sure from my experiences on that platform that this line is your problem:

```
const unsigned char *location = mem_u_const + 250 - sizeof(int);
```

The `mem_u_const` block was originally allocated by `new` for an array of characters.  Since `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1 and `sizeof(int)` is 4, you are adding 246 bytes.  This is not a multiple of 4.

On SPARC, the CPU can only read 4-byte words if they are aligned to 4-byte boundaries.  Your attempt to read a misaligned word is what causes the bus error.

I recommend allocating a `struct` with an array of `unsigned char` followed by an `int`, rather than a bunch of pointer math and casts like the one that caused this bug.

Comment: You want to say, that mem_u_const + 240 would be read without problem, because 240 is a multiple of 4?

Comment: I don’t think `new` is guaranteed to return a 4-byte-aligned address when you allocate `char` objects, and if portability is a concern at all, you don’t want your code to break when you recompile it for 64-bit code or on another architecture.  Instead of allocating a block of bytes, you should allocate a `struct`.  If the memory block needs to be interpreted in several different ways, allocate a `union` of `struct`s. More readable, elegant, portable and safer.

Comment: However, if you really don’t want to allocate a struct, you could instead allocate an array of `max_align_t`.  The storage for one of those is guaranteed to be properly-aligned for use as a pointer to any scalar type.  Or you could use `alignas`.

Comment: Thank you for help and answer, if I would have two "accepted" second would be yours.