# Is it a good idea to use memory pool with a cpu that need aligned memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

[CPU and Data alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025125/cpu-and-data-alignment)
In this question,Yann Ramin has said some cpus(ARM, or Intel SSE instructions)  require aligned memory and have undefined operation when doing unaligned accesses (or throw an exception). If I used a memory pool that doesn't handle this situation, would it make my application worse?

Answer (score 2):

Using unaligned memory will almost always be a bad idea, not only when it is explicitly unallowed. Even when it doesn't cause an error, if a memory access crosses a cache line boundary and in other cases (see Tony D's comment), it will be slower than if it didn't. Just use a memory pool that returns aligned addresses.

You can make a simple aligned memory pool by allocating a large chunk of bytes with `new` and breaking it into a given number of 4, 8, 16, ... byte blocks and returning the smallest fit. You could use a bitmap to keep track of which blocks are allocated. I should say this is inefficient. I assume this is more for fun/learning than production or you would just use `new`. Coding your own allocator isn't easy, you can look at implementations of `malloc` to see what I mean. It's a difficult balance between speed, space efficiency and fragmentation.

Comment: +1 for lots of good points, but regarding "when it doesn't cause an error, if a memory access crosses a cache line" - it's not just cache line boundaries... even unaligned accesses that are inside a cache line can be a fraction of the usual speed while they orchestrate an operation across words.  For example, reading a 32-bit `int` from addresses 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 etc..

Comment: You can make a simple aligned memory pool by allocating a large chunk of bytes with new and breaking it into a given number of 4, 8, 16, ... byte blocks and returning the smallest fit.      If the cpu need 8byte aligned memory boundries, would it be unwise to return a memory address that doesnt't match

Comment: When you allocate a block from `new` it is already aligned and when you break it up like I describe, alignment is preserved. So if you return an 8 byte block, it will be 8 byte aligned.

Comment: The last comment is only half true. When you allocate a block with `new`, it is aligned _to the allocation type's alignment_. Which, in the case of `char`, 1 byte. Of course in practice it's usually aligned to 8 bytes anyway (16 on some systems), but that is merely an implementation detail of the allocator. It is not something you may rely on.