# Why can't write internal flash of same address twice

Tags: embedded, stm32, flash-memory

I'm trying to write to internal flash of STM32F1xxC (2KB per page), I can write to flash after a page erase, which converts every byte of that page to 0xFF.

It's very strange that I can not write the **same address of flash twice**, it is only possible when the previous value of that address is "**0xFFFF**".

What's the reason of this limitation?
And also I was wondering why I can't write to odd addresses? (e.g. 0x803F0A1)

I don't think my question is platform (or vendor) specific, so I'm not adding any code.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: While flash technology imposes a number of restrictions that you describe, STM32 on-chip flash is further restricted in ways you should be very aware of since they impact severely on its utility in an application.  In that sense your question is "vendor specific", but you are right that no code is required to answer.

Comment: This is vendor specific and not generic...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is in the nature of flash memory that *write* operations only allow transition of a bit from 1 to 0.  To set a bit from 0 to 1 requires an *erase* operation and an erase operations applies to an entire erase block.  The size of an erase block varies between devices.

In most flash implementations it is possible to modify a word that has already been written if the only bit changes are from 1 to 0.  On the STM32F1xx however, even that is not possible, and since the word size is 16 bit, it is not possible to write a single byte if the other half of the word has been written.

The STM32F2xx (and also F4 and F7 ranges) partially solve this problem by allowing the flash to be written in 8, 16, and 32 bit modes, but it is still not possible to write a bit from 1 to zero when bits in the same word are already zero.

Another issue with STM32 on chip flash that you might need to be aware of is that during a write or erase operation, the bus stalls for a significant period.  On traditioanl flash parts, you can read from one page while anither is being written, but on STM32 the whole flash memory is blocked. Since normally instruction fetch is from flash memory, this read-blocking means that during a flash erase/write operation *no instructions are processed* - the entire processor core is in a *wait state* (peripherals continue to run - unless using DMA reads from flash perhaps).  For erase, the delay is page size dependent; on STM32F1xx this delay can be as much as 40ms, on F2 is 800ms!  This makes on-chip flash write/erase operations problematic in real-time systems.

While flash memory in general imposes restrictions on write/erase operations, STs implementation imposes its own additional restrictions as described above. You always need to match your non-volatile memory technology to the application, or write your application to work with the non-volatile memory available.  An external (off-chip) device may be appropriate in your case.  Most technologies are some sort of compromise on speed, usability, endurance, density and cost in one way or another, but you could consider an external flash, EEPROM, FRAM or battery backed SRAM for example.  If your processor lacks an external memory interface, or you cannot afford the necessary pin count to use an address bus accessed device, most technologies are available is serial-access devices through SPI or I2C for example.

Note also that the details of the STM32F1xx flash memory implementation are described in a separate document to the general user manual. Refer to [PM0075
Programming manual - STM32F10xxx Flash memory microcontrollers](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/10/98/e8/d4/2b/51/4b/f5/CD00283419.pdf/files/CD00283419.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.CD00283419.pdf)

To be fair to ST, the restrictive STM32 flash implementation is not entirely arbitrary. The implementation no doubt requires less die space than a "full" implementation allowing space for more peripherals, larger memories or smaller die size (for reduced cost).  Chip design involves many compromises, ST chose to compromise the flash flexibility for a large peripheral set it seems.

Comment: Note that ST provides code to emulate EEPROM behavior in flash. It uses a rolling memory approach which spreads out the writes across erasable sectors. That approach mitigates another limitation not directly mentioned above: the number of erase/program cycles is limited to about 10k (refer to reference manual), after which flash is at increasing risk of becoming corrupted. Example code for STM32F103 can be found there: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF1/blob/f5aaa9b45492d70585ade1dac4d1e33d5531c171/Projects/STM32F103RB-Nucleo/Applications/EEPROM/EEPROM_Emulation/

Comment: @gg99 : EEPROM emulation is practical on only a subset of STM32 devices (those with small and equal-sized flash pages.  However it does apply to STM32F1xx in this question. (refer to [AN2594](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2594-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf))  for some other STM32 parts refer also to [AN4894](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2594-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It not very strange, but the rule with flash, because of the underlying technology (which I will not dare to explain, I'm not a physicist). Have a look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Block_erasure

> A location can, however, be rewritten as long as the new value's 0
>   bits are a superset of the over-written values. For example, a nibble
>   value may be erased to 1111, then written as 1110. Successive writes
>   to that nibble can change it to 1010, then 0010, and finally 0000.
>   Essentially, erasure sets all bits to 1, and programming can only
>   clear bits to 0.

As for:

> And also I was wondering why I can't write to odd addresses?

This is a *memory alignment* limitation of your CPU - a very common one, don't blame it for that! A good explanation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025225/5257515

So, to write to an unaligned address, you'll have to write to the aligned address before it as well:

- load the 16 (or 32 bits, depending on your alignment granularity limitation) bits memory aligned address value, which include the part you're interested in,
- change this part leaving the rest untouched,
- write back the new 16 (or 32) bits value to the memory aligned address.

EDIT:

For specific insight to STM32F1xx even more restrictive design, be sure to look at @Clifford comment.

Comment: On STM32F1xx the read-modify-write technique will not work.  ST's implementation is even more restrictive than you have described.  It is writable in 16 bit words a word may not be written if *any* of teh bits are zero (i.e. is the word has previously been written).

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the insight on the STM32F1xx, my answer is very broad/all around.

Comment: Yes, STM32 flash is a bit of a "gotcha" - that is not the only problem with it - normally you can read one page while writing/erasing another, but in STM32 the entire flash bus stalls, so no no code in flash runs - stalling execution for significant periods (tens of milliseconds).

Comment: @Clifford STM32 flash allows you to write all zeroes to a flash word, after you've written it with a value. They even use it in one of their app notes where they simulate EEPROM in flash: EEPROM emulation in STM32F0xx microcontrollers (AN4061)

Comment: @NZD Your comment might better have been applied to _my_ answer, where I have described STM32 behaviour in detail. Is this specifically a restriction of whole word to zero, so the possible _word_  transitions are _all-ones->non -zero->zero_? Is it specific to F0, or true of all STM32?

Comment: @Clifford AFAIK this holds for all STM32 devices, and yes: the possible word transitions are all-ones->non-zero->zero. Some STM32 devices are less restrictive and do allow writing any bit from 1 to 0, e.g. STM32F72x devices. Check the reference manual for your device family to make sure which situation applies.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to Clifford response, it shall be noted that the STM32 flash controller allow a second write to a word if the value is 0x0000.
This allows to have 3 states on word between flash page erase:

1. 0xffff after page erase
2. 0xxxxx any value written
3. 0x0000 a second and last write of 0.

This can be very handy when building a dynamic data storage in flash (like EEPROM emulation) to have states 'free', 'in use' and 'deleted' for example.