# What does *(int*)(buffer) mean?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In a c++ code I am reading, found the following.
Can anyone help me understand what does the following statements do?

```
char buffer[4096];
// some code
int size = *(int*)(buffer);
```

Comment: Do you know what `(int*)buffer` means? If not read about *casting*. Do you know what the unary dereference operator `*` does (for example what happens if you have `*some_pointer`)? If not read about that too. Then just combine the knowledge about each subject, like they are combined in expression you're wondering about.

Comment: This statement also possibly causes alignment exception on some architectures.

Comment: This statement also causes undefined behavior.

Comment: It's taking the address of `buffer`, casting it to `int *`, then dereferencing the resulting pointer, which is undefined behavior.  In particular, there is no guarantee that `buffer` is aligned on an accept `int` boundary.  The behavior is undefined.  You should not attempt to run this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: this code is bad, forget about it and move on.

---

`(buffer)` This parenthesis means that the programmer was insecure of their own programming abilities.

Since `buffer` is an array of characters, using the identifier `buffer` on its own gives you a pointer to the first element: a `char` pointer.

`(int*)` This is a cast, converting the `char` pointer to an `int` pointer.

`*` takes the contents of that integer pointer and the result is stored in the integer `size`.

Please note that this code is completely unsafe. Many pointer conversions invoke poorly-defined behavior. There might be alignment issues. There might be pointer aliasing issues (Google "strict aliasing rule"). This particular code is also endianess-dependent, meaning that it requires that the contents of the character array has a given byte order.

Overall, it does not make any sense to use signed types like `int` or  `char` (maybe signed) when doing things like this. In particular, the `char` type is very problematic since it has implementation-defined signedness and should be avoided. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead.

Slightly less bad code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t buffer[4096];
// some code
uint32_t size = *(uint32_t*)buffer;
```

Comment: I think your example code should not use pointer dereference trick at all. Using `memcpy` would still have possible endianness issue, but at least there would not be UB.

Comment: How is code that still has the same undefined behavior less bad?

Comment: @2501 Because it doesn't have the mentioned type problems. Demonstrating how to fix that was the purpose of the code snippet. To fix the undefined behavior, you would need to do something far more drastical.

Comment: There's a problem with the proposed alternative: it imposes a constraint that is not present in the original code, namely, that the target hardware must provide an 8-bit native type and a 32-bit native type. That might be a valid change, but code samples that impose different requirements from the original code should point out those differences. `unsigned char` will always exist; `uint8_t` might not.

Answer (score 14):

```
char buffer[4096];//this is an array of 4096 characters
// some code

int size = *(int*)(buffer);
```

Will cast the(decayed) character pointer,which is `buffer`, to an integer pointer. It then dereferences it to get an **integer value**. The integer value you get from this will be composed of the first 4 character values of the `buffer` array assuming the size of `int` is 4 bytes in your machine, or in general will be composed of `sizeof(int)` characters.

In other words, the memory representation of the first `sizeof(int)` characters of the `buffer` array will be treated as though they represent a single integer value,since now it is pointed to by an integer pointer, and that will be stored in the `size` integer variable when that integer pointer is dereferenced.

That being said, as it has been stated repeatedly in the comments section, this code is unsafe. One thing that comes to mind is, some CPUs have a strict alignment requirements(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025125/cpu-and-data-alignment)), and in this case there is no guarantee that the address of the first element of the `buffer` array complies with the alignment requirement of an integer resulting in undefined operation in those CPUs.

See @Lundin answer for even more reason why this code is unsafe and may not give you the result you were looking for.

Comment: @user694733, true, it could crash on some architectures due to a bad  memory alignment for a pointer to `int`

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for your feedback, I've tried to mention one reason that i know will result in undefined operation on some CPUs. The answer by Lundin goes in more detail about the issues with this code and i feel like i would be echoing what has already being said.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone help me understand what does the following statements do?

The first statement :

```
char buffer[4096];
```

declares an array of `chars` with size `4096`.

The second statement :

```
int size = *(int*)(buffer);
```

**1.** First takes the decayed character pointer to the array `buffer` (also named `buffer`), which is a pointer pointing to its first element, set at the time of its declaration

**2.** Then casts it to pointer to `int`, or `int*`

**3.** Finally, assigns the content of this pointer (which will be of type `int`) to variable `size`.

Comment: "first takes the address of array `buffer`" is wrong, getting the address of `buffer` would be `&buffer`. Instead `buffer` *decays to a pointer* to its first element.

Comment: I cannot give upvote, until answer answer also explains why this code is broken and should not be used.

Comment: @user694733 Indeed, if only one answer clearly explained why this is ub.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the address of `buffer[0]`, casts it to an `int*`, dereferences that, and uses the dereferenced value to initialize `size`. In other words, it takes the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of `buffer`, pretends those bytes are an `int`, and stores that int's value in `size`.

Comment: It doesn't *directly* take the address of `buffer[0]`. Instead the array *decays* to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: I cannot give upvote, until answer answer also explains why this code is broken and should not be used.