# What does `align` mean in c++ class hierarchy?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
class Student{
public:
    int id;
    int age;
};
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

If we compile such a program using gcc and `-fdump-class-hierarchy` option, gcc will produce a `.class` file like this:

```
Class Student
   size=8 align=4
   base size=8 base align=4
Student (0x0x7fbafc4a05a0) 0
```

compile command:

```
g++ file.cpp -o file -fdump-class-hierarchy
```

Obviously `size` is class size.but what do `align`, `base align` and `base size` mean in this file?

Comment: Do you know what *alignment* (in terms of memory and addresses) means?

Comment: @Zeta no, I dont know.

Comment: Then you should start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025125/cpu-and-data-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Alignment relates to where in memory a computer stores its for example an integer, Your student class has two of them. Since an int is generally 4 bytes long it might be much more efficient to load and store when the representation of an int is aligned on a multiple of 4.